# Python class property error

Tags: python, python-2.7

[image: error print like this]
[image: calling code]
[image: class definition]

I don't understand why `__init__` was called twice and it yields different types of property?

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, dataobj):
        self._dataobj = dataobj
        print 'called inside test function %s' % type(self._dataobj)

    @property
    def dataobj(self):
        return self._dataobj
```

`Test(locals())` gives:

```
called inside test function <type 'dict'>
called inside test function <class 'Test'>
```

This seems like a pass ref/value issue, but I don't understand why it gives different types
and is called twice. many thanks!

Comment: Cannot reproduce on my machine

Comment: I can't reproduce either.  All I see is the first message (as expected)

Comment: Can you show a copy-pasted interpreter session or screenshot?

Comment: Check your code, maybe you mistyped it like `Test(Test(locals()))`

Comment: added some screenshot

Comment: Looks to me like some other part of your code is creating a `Backtest` with a `Backtest` for a data object.

Comment: I checked, I can't find any. but here's the class code anyway. https://github.com/arippbbc/pybacktest/blob/master/pybacktest/backtest.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, dataobj):
        self._dataobj = dataobj
        print 'called inside test function %s' % type(self._dataobj),self._dataobj

    @property
    def dataobj(self):
        return self._dataobj

Test(Test(locals()))
```

I guess you have mistyped the call for the class Test. or else you would not have got that result. Test(Test(locals())) will produce the result that you have got.

Comment: Right, 

    Test(locals())
    called inside test function <type 'dict'>
    <__main__.Test object at 0x0296D0B0>

 works for me, too.

Comment: you are right, I didn't notice there is another class calls constructor directly. So I don't have to return a class 'test', but parameter of 'test' constructor. Thank you!